# Linq to xml get list of lists

Tags: c#, list, linq-to-xml

I have an XML

```
    <Treatments>
        <Treatment>
            <Date>...</Date>
            <Photos>
               <Photo>
                  <Path>...<Path>
                  <Contour>
                      <Line X1 = ... Y1 = ... X2 = ... Y2 = ...>
                      <Line X1 = ... Y1 = ... X2 = ... Y2 = ...>
                      <Line X1 = ... Y1 = ... X2 = ... Y2 = ...>
                      <Line X1 = ... Y1 = ... X2 = ... Y2 = ...>
                  <Contour>
               </Photo>
               <Photo>
                  <Path>...<Path>
                  <Contour>
                      <Line X1 = ... Y1 = ... X2 = ... Y2 = ...>
                      <Line X1 = ... Y1 = ... X2 = ... Y2 = ...>
                      <Line X1 = ... Y1 = ... X2 = ... Y2 = ...>
                      <Line X1 = ... Y1 = ... X2 = ... Y2 = ...>
                  <Contour>
               </Photo>
            </Photos>
         </Treatment>
         <Treatment>
            .
            .
         </Treatment
    </Treatments>
```

Beforehand I had it without the `<Contour>` element.
And my code was

```
IEnumerable<XElement> treats =
        from t in xdoc.Descendants("Treatment")
        where (string)t.Element("Date").Value == _Date
        select t;

List<TreatmentData> tl = new List<TreatmentData>();

foreach (XElement treat in treats)
{
   TreatmentData td = new TreatmentData();
   td.Date = treat.Element("Date").Value;
   // td.Photos is a List<string>
   td.Photos = treat.Element("Photos").Elements("Path").Select(c => c.Value).ToList();
   tl.Add(td);
}
```

I don't understand how to get the list of lines to each list of photos.
I am new to linq can anybody tell me the correct way of doing it please?

Comment: Could you show the definition of `TreatmentData` and also provide a few more details on what results you're hoping to get?

Comment: It's like Florian wrote. Only I was using List instead of IEnumerable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd rather use Xml Deserialization but with Linq2XML it would look like this (used a unittest to show/prove functionality):

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        string xml = @"
<Treatments>
    <Treatment>
        <Date>2015-04-13</Date>
        <Photos>
           <Photo>
              <Path>...</Path>
              <Contour>
                  <Line X1 = ""1"" Y1 = ""1"" X2 = ""155"" Y2 = ""1""/>
                  <Line X1 = ""133"" Y1 = ""1"" X2 = ""122"" Y2 = ""1""/>
              </Contour>
           </Photo>              
         </Photos>
     </Treatment>
</Treatments>";
        XElement xelement = XElement.Parse(xml);

        List<TreatmentData> test = xelement.Elements("Treatment")
            .Select(treatmentNode => new TreatmentData
                                     {
                                         Date = DateTime.ParseExact(treatmentNode.Element("Date").Value, "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                                         Photos = treatmentNode.Element("Photos").Elements("Photo")
                                            .Select(photoNode => new Photo
                                                                {
                                                                   Path = photoNode.Element("Path").Value,
                                                                   Lines = photoNode.Element("Contour").Elements("Line")
                                                                   .Select(lineNode => new Line
                                                                                        {
                                                                                            X1 = int.Parse(lineNode.Attribute("X1").Value),
                                                                                            Y1 = int.Parse(lineNode.Attribute("Y1").Value),
                                                                                            X2 = int.Parse(lineNode.Attribute("X2").Value),
                                                                                            Y2 = int.Parse(lineNode.Attribute("Y2").Value),
                                                                            }).ToArray()
                                                       }).ToArray()
                                     }).ToList();

        Assert.AreEqual(155,test.First().Photos.First().Lines.First().X2);


    }
}
public class TreatmentData
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Photo> Photos { get; set; }

}

public class Photo
{
    public string Path { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Line> Lines { get; set; }

}

public class Line
{
    public int X1 { get; set; }
    public int Y1 { get; set; }
    public int X2 { get; set; }
    public int Y2 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I was just ready to post something virtually identical ;) Note that simply using `Descendents("Photo")` and `Descendents("Line")` saves some typing.